# Can I add where clauses after putting limit on a scoped query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model called Game in which I build up a scoped query.

Something like:

```
games = Game.scoped
games = games.team(team_name) if team_name
games = game.opponent(opponent_name) if opponent_name

total_games = games
```

I then calculate several subsets like:

```
wins = games.where("team_score > opponent_score").count
losses = games.where("opponent_score > team_score").count
```

Everything is great. Then I decided that I want to limit the original scope to show the last X number of games.

```
total_games = games.limit(10)
```

If there are 100 games that match what I want for total_games, and then I add .limit(10) - it gets the last 10. Great. But now calling

```
total_games.where("team_score > opponent_score").count
```

will reach back beyond the last 10, and into results that aren't part of total_games. Since adding .limit(10), I'll always get 10 total games, but also 10 wins, and 10 losses.

After typing this all out, I've realized that the cases where I want to use limit are for showing a smaller set of results - so I'll probably end up just looping through the results to calculate things like wins and losses (instead of doing separate queries as in my subsets above).

I tried this out when total_games had hundreds or thousands of results, and it's significantly slower to loop through than it is to just do separate queries for the subsets.

So, now I must know - what is the best way to limit a scoped query, and then do future queries of those results that restrict themselves results returned by the original .limit(x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want to do without separating your query into two steps, first getting 10 games from `total_games` and making the DB query with `all`:

```
last_10_games = total_games.limit(10).all
```

then selecting from the resulting array and getting the size of the result:

```
wins = last_10_games.select { |g| g.team_score > g.opponent_score }.count
losses = last_10_games.select { |g| g.opponent_score > g.team_score }.count
```

I know this is not exactly what you asked for, but I think it's probably the most straightforward solution to the problem.